# How do I set a class on a parent element when a route is the first one loaded?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember demo app that works fine if the first route loaded is 'index', 'list' or 'list/index', but not if the first route loaded is 'list/show'.  Code is at https://github.com/DougReeder/beta-list , demo is running at https://ember-demo.surge.sh To see the problem, set your window narrower than 640px and surf to https://ember-demo.surge.sh/list/5  You'll see the list panel, rather than the detail panel.

The underlying problem is that, when the route is 'list/show', the divs with class 'panelList' and 'panelDetail' should also have the class 'right'.

I can't set this in the template, because panelList and panelDetail are created by the parent 'list' template.  If I move panelList and panelDetail to the child templates 'list/index' and 'list/show', then the list gets re-rendered when going from 'list/index' to 'list/show' which would be a terrible performance hit.

Currently, I use the 'didTransition' action to toggle the class 'right'.  This is called both then transitioning from 'list/index' to 'list/show', and when 'list/show' is the initial route. Unfortunately, if 'list/show' is the first route, none of the DOM elements exist when 'didTransition' is called.

I can envision two routes to a solution, but don't know how to implement either:

1. Toggle the class 'right' on some action which happens after DOM elements exist.
2. Insert conditional code in the 'list' template, which sets the class 'right' on 'panelList' and 'panelDetail' if the actual route is 'list/show'.

Suggestions?

Comment: I guess you have update your code on github; you are no longer using `didTransition` hooks anymore? Can you give an update about whether your are still in need of a help?

Answer (score 1):

Answer current as of Ember v2.12.0

You can use the [link-to helper](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_link-to) to render elements other than links, with styles that change based on the route. Utilizing the `activeClass`, `current-when`, and `tagName` properties, you can basically have that element be styled however you want depending on which route you are on. For example, to render your panelList div:

```
{{#link-to tagName='div' classNames='panelList' activeClass='right' current-when='list/show'}}
  More markup
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but those properties style the DOM element created by the link-to.  I need to style an *ancestor* of the link-to element.

Comment: @DougReeder I don't think you understand my answer. You can take any element in your app and render it with a link-to. I am suggesting that you use link-to to render whatever element it is that you want styled based on the route. It doesn't have to be a link. I am already using this in a large production application. This teaches me a lesson, I get nothing but downvotes when I answer Ember questions on StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 0):

I love a trick with empty component. In `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement` hooks you can add and remove a css class from parent element or (I like it better) body. Here is a code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    bodyClass: '',
    didInsertElement() {
        const bodyClass = this.get('bodyClass');
        if (bodyClass) {
            Ember.$('body').addClass(bodyClass);
        }
    },
    willDestroyElement() {
        const bodyClass = this.get('bodyClass');
        if (bodyClass) {
            Ember.$('body').removeClass(bodyClass);
        }
    }
});
```

I use it in template (in my example it's a template of `player` route) like this

```
{{body-class bodyClass='player-page-active'}}
```

To apply classes to parent element, you can use `this.$().parent()`, but using body is more reliable. Note that this component will create an empty div, but it shouldn't be a problem (can be in rare cases, fix it with `classNames` and css if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Sukima suggested looking at currentRouteName, and I thus found [hschillig's solution](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-get-current-route-name/10324/8), which I simplified for my case. In the controller, I created an `isShow` function:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  routing: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  isShow: function() {
    var currentRouteName = this.get('routing').get('currentRouteName');
    return currentRouteName === 'list.show';
  }.property('routing.currentRouteName'),
```

In the template, I now use the `if` helper:

```
  <div class="panelList {{if isShow 'right'}}">
```

RustyToms's answer eliminates the need for adding a function to the Controller, at the expense of being less semantic.